# Update MySQL datetime column with subtracted value from another row in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, sql-update

I am trying to update/set the *endTime-column* my table called **rounds**, described below

`+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | varchar(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| startTime | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| endTime   | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

The values (20+, but limited here) are as follows

[image]

The values for columns name and startTime are consumed from a JSON api and fed into the database. But I need to set the endTime in order to do some calculating on other events that take place between these dates. It is rounds in a game.

The endTime is known. It is one (1) minute before the startTime of the next round.

I tried this

```
UPDATE rounds 
SET endTime = date_sub((SELECT startTime FROM new_tbl WHERE DATE(startTime) > NOW() ORDER BY startTime ASC LIMIT 1), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

(**new_tbl** is an exact copy of the table **rounds** because I got lost in a join-jungle)

Which of course just updated all endTimes with the same, albeit correct, endTime for the April round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions for this:

```
update rounds r
inner join (
    select r.id, lead(startTime) over(order by startTime) leadStartTime
    from rounds
) r1 on r1.id = r.id
set r.endTime = r1.leadStartTime - interval 1 minute
```

In earlier versions, it is a bit more complicated. Here is an approach that emulates `lead()` with a correlated subquery:

```
update rounds r
inner join (
    select 
        t.id, 
        (select min(t1.startTime) from rounds t1 where t1.startTime > t.startTime) leadStartTime
    from rounds t
) r1 on r1.id = r.id
set r.endTime = r1.leadStartTime - interval 1 minute
```